# Swiper slider фиксированная ширина слайда

Tags: jquery, slider, swiper

Как задать фиксированную ширину слайдам?

Answer (score 3):

Прошу прощения, разобрался)

```
slidesPerView: 'auto'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 new Swiper(".swiper-filter", {
    slidesPerView: 4,
    spaceBetween: 15,
 });
```

В данном случае в видимой области будет 4 слайда с одинаковой шириной, если нужно чтобы у слайдов была разная ширина то установить свойство `slidesPerView: 'auto'` а саму ширину уже настраивать в css